# environment setup for Importing a userdefined module

Tags: 13.04, python, environment-variables

I am creating an User defined module an .so file and importing that in the python module.

The functions in the library are not responding as expected.

What are the environment variables to be set to include all the library paths and headers?

Where exactly the .so file to be present ( I am placing in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages)?

Is there any other settings need to done for referring the library paths and headers?

Answer (score 1):

If you already put your .so file in `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`, try to make a new python file (in the same dir) named as 'my_lib.py'.

Put the below code in it:

```
def __bootstrap__():
   global __bootstrap__, __loader__, __file__
   import sys, pkg_resources, imp
   __file__ = pkg_resources.resource_filename(__name__,'hello_world.so')
   __loader__ = None; del __bootstrap__, __loader__
   imp.load_dynamic(__name__,__file__)
__bootstrap__()
```

You may need to install `python-pkg-resources`:

```
sudo apt-get install python-pkg-resources
```

Now you can import this my_lib as:

```
>>> import my_lib
```

**EDIT**: To properly manage several extensions, I would recommend to package them using [`distutils`](https://docs.python.org/2/extending/building.html) and then install them using just

```
./setup.py build
sudo ./setup.py install
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10968309/how-to-import-python-module-from-so-file)

Comment: is there any other setting need to done? Where should I place my third party libraries and how Python will look into it?

Comment: Yo mean other .so or additional .py files?

Comment: additional .so files and header files

Comment: To properly manage several extensions, I would recommend to package them using [distutils](https://docs.python.org/2/extending/building.html) and then install them using just `sudo ./setup.py build install`

Comment: Can you give me an example please

Comment: I can only suggest the official doc: https://docs.python.org/2/extending/extending.html

Comment: Did you try my first proposal? If it works could you please vote (or even accept) my answer? The building process is a bit off topic here

Comment: import my_lib
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "my_lib.py", line 7, in <module>
    __bootstrap__()
  File "my_lib.py", line 6, in __bootstrap__
    imp.load_dynamic(__name__,__file__)
ImportError: dynamic module does not define init function (initmy_lib)   Getting this import error

Comment: Did you use the PyMODINIT_FUNC macro before initmy_lib?

Comment: Hi @SylvainPineau, this answers helps a lot! (Someone green tick it please). However, I have a different situation here. I don't want the newly created `filename.py` to be created for `filename.so` because I don't think importing filename and using it's functions as written in `filename.so`(via `filename.pyx`) works with the presence of `filename.py`. Help please.